# Calling DIVs from master page to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

On master page i have 2 class which needs to be inherited on test.aspx

```
<div class="1"> 
   <div class="2">

    </div>
 </div>
```

And i have one contentplaceholder, how will i inherit these div on to test.aspx page ?

Comment: Sorry, but your question isn't clear. Is it about WebForms or ASP.NET MVC (**review your tags**)? You have a master page and view pages, but we don't know it (**add your code to your quesion**). Finally, what do you mean by "inherit"?

Comment: I have on masterpage html menu, and i want it to show on other templates using master page.

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX. Any markup (HTML code) that is outside the contentplaceholder will be present on any child page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="1"> 
   <div class="2">
<asp:ContentPlaceholder  attribute goes here></asp:ContentPlaceholder>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Create a new webform and set master page to the said one. The two divs and its classes will automatically get called.